# Change the tag eink to e-ink

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

I suggest to rename the tag [eink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eink) to [e-ink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-ink) for better readability.

I was going to tag a question [e-ink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-ink) but the autocomplete wizard suggested to me the already-used [eink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree.

Actually, it should be "E Ink," because "E Ink" is the trade name of E Ink Corporation, which created the technology. You can't have a space in a tag name on Stack Exchange sites, however, so [e-ink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-ink) would be the correct tag, not [eink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eink).

Answer (score 2):

I agree for exactly the reason Ed Cottrell has said. I have created a tag synonym that will map the [eink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eink) tag to [e-ink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-ink). I have also merged any existing questions (there were 11 at the time) so that the new tag [e-ink](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-ink) is displayed instead of the old tag.